# Guzzle 6 PUT request shows deprecated method

Tags: http, request, guzzle, laravel-5.3

I am using guzzle http 6 to send a put request into my server. In their documentation, it says that the way to send a put request with data is like

```
$client->request('PUT', $url, ['body' => 'foo']);
```

but when i tried i got this error

[image]

just to mention, i am using guzzle http on laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Your third argument should be the headers. The fourth should be the body.

Below an example from http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html?highlight=put

```
$headers = ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'];
$body = 'hello!';
$request = new Request('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', $headers, $body);
```

In your case, it should be:

```
$client->request('PUT', $url, [], ['body' => 'foo']);
```

Comment: it clears the previous error but now I am facing another problem. my request now caught exception. here is my code -

Comment: try{

                $response = $client->request($method, $url, [], [
                    
                    'body' =>$data
                ]);

                $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                return $result;

            }

            catch (RequestException $e) {
                echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
                if ($e->hasResponse()) 
                {
                    return 'unsuccessful';
                    
                }
            }